# The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Tags: java, parsing, json

I am returning a `json` from my class:

```
@POST("/test")
    @PermitAll
    public JSONObject test(Map form) {

    JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
    json.put("key1",1);
    json.put("key2",2);
        return json;
    }
```

now I want to get this json from "`getInputStream`" and parse it to see if `key1` exists:

```
String output = "";

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}

output=output.toString();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("output", output);

if (jsonObj.get("output") != null){
    **//search for key1 in output**
    System.out.println("key1 exists");
}else{
    System.out.println("key1 doesnt exist");
} 
reader.close();
```

How can I convert `output` to `JSONObject` and search for "key1"?

I tried following but I got errors after arrows:

```
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(output);  ---> The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined
JSONObject data = jObject.getJSONObject("data"); ---> The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject
String projectname = data.getString("name"); ----> The method getString(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject
```

Comment: What library does JSONObject come from? You should have access to the given API and find a way to convert to string to an JSONObject object.

Comment: What's the package of your class ? There is a constructor if you use org.json.JSONObject: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: I'm using json-simple-1.1.1.jar.

Comment: So read the documentation for [*that* library](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).. or switch to using the "expected" JSON library for the code provided.

Comment: Yes, try these examples: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(output);
```

Try this.

And then you can verify the existence of the field using:

```
jsonObject.has("key1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the object using a parser.  Check out the documentation here: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples